# Null Reference when using StructureMap in Windows Form App C#

Tags: c#, dependencies, code-injection, structuremap

I am a newbie in using StructureMap as DI approach in windows form application.
Now my problem is i am getting a null reference on the IServicesTasks object after app start. Please see my initial codes below.

This is the Main method of the winform app.

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", @"C:\Tools\PWS.Tool\EntityModel");
    var container = Container.For<PWSInterfaceRegistry>();
    var app = container.GetInstance<FacadeInterface>();
    Application.Run(new pws());
}
```

This is the event for the Save button.

```
private void cmdSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool success = false;

    <<mappings>>

    FacadeInterface facadeService = new FacadeInterface();
    success = facadeService.CreateAssignments(request);
}
```

The interface.

```
public interface IServiceTasks
{
    bool CreateAssignment(SEntities.AssignmentEntityRequest request);
}
```

And the method implementing the interface

```
public class FacadeInterface : IInterfaceTasks
{
    private Service.IServiceTasks _task;

    //public FacadeInterface()
    //{
    //    CreateAssignmentService _service = new CreateAssignmentService();
    //    Service.IServiceTasks service_tasks = (Service.IServiceTasks)_service;
    //    _task = service_tasks;
    //}
    public FacadeInterface() { }
    public FacadeInterface(Service.IServiceTasks tasks)
    {
        _task = tasks;
    }

    public bool CreateAssignments(IEntities.AssignmentEntityRequest request)
    {

        bool response = false;
        Helpers.Helpers mapper = new Helpers.Helpers();
        var assignmentRequest = new SEntities.AssignmentEntityRequest();
        assignmentRequest = mapper.MapInterfacetoServiceRequest(request);
        response = _task.CreateAssignment(assignmentRequest); --> i am getting a null reference here for the _task instance even if it was initialize upon application start
        return response;
    }

    public bool CreateProjects(IEntities.ProjectEntityRequest request)
    {
        bool response = false;
        Helpers.Helpers mapper = new Helpers.Helpers();
        var projectRequest = new SEntities.ProjectEntityRequest();
        projectRequest = mapper.MapInterfacetoServiceRequest(request);
        //response = _task.(projectRequest);
        return response;
    }
}
```

PWSInterfaceRegistry method

```
public class PWSInterfaceRegistry : Registry
{
    public PWSInterfaceRegistry()
    {
        Scan(scan =>
        {
            scan.TheCallingAssembly();
            scan.WithDefaultConventions();
        });
        For<Service.IServiceTasks>().Use<CreateAssignmentService>();
    }
}
```

Comment: `_task`  is never set

Comment: _task is being set through the container on the Main method.

Comment: Ok than, what is the value of _task before the error? try `if(_task ==null){throw new exeption("Firewizz was right");}` before the line where it all goes south

Comment: basically, that is my problem, _task is being initialized upon application start but ends up having null value when it hits the line. this is related to Structure Map approach in dependency injection

Comment: ok then remove `public FacadeInterface() { }` if it depends on _task being set. My guess is you get the error where you should inject the task ;)

Comment: but my guess is `FacadeInterface facadeService = new FacadeInterface(new ???);`

Comment: but where you trying to do property or method injection?? see http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/dependencyinjection/implementation-of-dependency-injection-pattern-in-csharp

Comment: my implementation is all based here, http://ardalis.com/using-structuremap-4-in-a-console-app